# invertibility, derivative, and difference quotient

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is an invertible differentiable function, that the domain of $f^{-1}$ contains an interval around $a$, and that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $a$ and that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $a$. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $a$ and that
$$
\bigl( f^{-1} \bigr)'(a) = \frac {1}{f'\bigl(f^{-1}(a)\bigr)}.
$$

The problem here is that I can not use the chain rule as it makes an assumption that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, what if $f'(a)=0$ then $f'(a)$ is not differentiable. Can I write down a difference quotient?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you need to assume that $$f^{\prime}(f^{-1}(a))\neq 0$$. Take $$f(x)=x^{1/3}$$ for a counter example of the theorem without it. With this additional assumption, use the difference quotient:
Let $$b=f^{-1}(a)$$.

$$\frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(a)}{x-a}=\frac{y-b}{x-a}=\frac{y-b}{f(y)-f(b)}$$

That's the algebra of it. If you need help with the analysis as well, I'm happy to add the details.

edit:

### Calculus answer

$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{y\to b}\frac{y-b}{f(y)-f(b)}=\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(b)}=\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(f^{-1}(a))}$

### Analysis answer

Let $f$ be invertible, differentiable, with $f^{-1}$ continuous on an interval containing $a=f(b)$. Furthermore, let $f^{\prime}(b)\neq 0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, and choose $\delta>0$ such that $\vert y-b\vert<\delta$ implies that $\left\vert \frac{1}{\frac{f(y)-b}{y-b}}-\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(b)}\right\vert<\epsilon$. We can do this because $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)=g(c)\neq 0$ implies $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{g(c)}$ for all functions $g$ and numbers $c$. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $a$, there is $\eta>0$ such that $\vert x-a\vert<\eta$ implies $\vert f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(a)\vert<\delta$.

So for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\eta>0$ such that $$\vert x-a\vert<\eta$$ implies that $$\left\vert\frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(a)}{x-a}-\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(f^{-1}(a))}\right\vert=\left\vert \frac{1}{\frac{f(f^{-1}(x))-b}{f^{-1}(x)-b}}-\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(b)}\right\vert<\epsilon$$ (because $\vert f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(a)\vert=\vert f^{-1}(x)-b\vert<\delta$.)

Thus $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(a)}{x-a}=\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(f^{-1}(a))}$, and we see that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: and so because that limit exists, then the inverse is differentiable at A?